# Error url bloqueda app sesion facebook

Tags: facebook

Creé una App de Facebook para el registro en mi web y me aparece esto :

> url bloqueada: la redirección ha fallado porque la uri no está
>   incluida en la lista de autorizados oauth de cliente de la aplicación.
>   comprueba que el acceso "oauth" de cliente y web estén activados y
>   añade todos los dominios de tus aplicaciones como uri de redirección
>   "oauth"

Puse correctamente el dominio en la config de la app y luego en la config de inicio de sesion de facebook. Con el https incluido.

Comment: Estás usando algún Framework?

Comment: Por favor añade algo más de información a la pregunta: ¿qué dominio tienes? ¿qué dominio has puesto en la configuración de facebook?

Answer (score 4):

Además de todo lo que tiene que ver con la especificación de tu App y la correcta conexión de esta misma, realizandola con su respectivo identificador y clave secreta, se debe de agregar la URL que es la dirección a la cual Facebook va a redireccionar luego de comprobar los datos, para ello debes de dirigirte a **Inicio de sesión con Facebook** y luego a **Configuración**  en [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y posteriormente añadir en **URI de redireccionamiento de OAuth válidos** la dirección que completa el inicio de sesión con Facebook en tu App

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de usar el Framework Django

> https://tuapp/oauth/complete/facebook

En el caso de usar Laravel

> https://tuapp/auth/facebook/callback

Comment: Buen dato, funciona correcto. 
En symfony usando fosuserbundle y hwioauthbundle se puede poner así:

? (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/connect/check-facebook`?)    Tambien funciona con google!!!

Gracias!!!

Comment: @FernandoLeon No olvides darle ✔ si esta respuesta a solucionado tu problema